# Exception encountered during startup: cdc_raw_directory is missing and -Dcassandra.storagedir is not set

Tags: cassandra

I have installed **Cassandra** for Windows x64 distributed by Datastax following the directions here:
[*Installing DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra 3.x for Windows*](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra_win/3.x/cassandra/install/installWin.html)

However, even though the installation goes through successfully, the service fails to start with the following error. I am using **Windows 7 x64**, I used elevated command prompt to kick off the installation.

> ERROR [main] 2016-10-11 13:40:22,710 CassandraDaemon.java:747 -
>   Exception encountered during startup: cdc_raw_directory is missing and
>   -Dcassandra.storagedir is not set

Any suggestions? I am not sure what I should set the `cdc_raw_directory` or `Dcassandra.storagedir` to.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue with DataStax 3.9

I got it to start doing the following
Edit

```
DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra.yaml
```

Uncomment the cdc_raw_directory and set it to

```
cdc_raw_directory: "C:/Program Files/DataStax-DDC/data/cdc_raw"
```

After this the service will start